# Python Change Permission of Dir and all Subdirs

Tags: python, permissions

I'm trying to execute the following command in Python:

```
shutil.rmtree('/var/www')
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www'
```

I've tried executing this command before that command to change permissions on the directory

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'chmod', '-R', '777', '/var/www'])
```

Which I guess is working because it asks me for my sudo password and doesn't throw an error, however when I then reach the rmtree command it still throws a

```
Permission denied: '/var/www'
```

What am I doing wrong? Also I need this to work without asking for my sudo password during execution. Is there a way to put my password into the Python script?

Thanks

Comment: have you changed the ownership of the directory? because you can't change the mod of the root directory from normal user

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the group ownership of that directory, make sure that your `username` is added to this group which has write permissions to all files in the path:

```
chmod -R g+w /var/www/
```

As for the second pat of your question, `sudo` can read the password from the standard input using the `-S` flag which can be included in your script. Here's an example:

```
$ echo "password" | sudo -S <command>
```

A quick look at the [`man sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html) page:

> -S, --stdin
>
> Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the
>   standard input instead of using the terminal device. The password must
>   be followed by a newline character.

Another way of doing that (which needs to be added to your script as well):

```
sudo -S <<< "password" command
```

Another approach is to disable password prompt by editing the `sudoers` file using the `visudo` command and add the following line:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The above line will allow `username` to run all commands (the last `ALL`) under any users without prompting for a password.

A secure and more restricted way of doing that is to use:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python myscript.py
```

This time, we have limited the `username` for that type of execution but for a single command `/usr/bin/python myscript.py`.

I'd also prefer checking the permissions carefully and testing these commands directly from the shell before using it in your python script. It could save you a lot of time of troubleshooting.